# Negating a button when an array is empty

Tags: ios, arrays, button, switch-statement, label

Im developing in Swift and I am displaying one string from an array by clicking a button. However, after the array is empty and the last string of the array is displayed, I want the user to be unable to click on the button since there are no more strings to display and the array is empty. So far I have crafted code to where the button is disabled after the array is empty but it stays disabled even after I had more strings to the array (by clicking another button). Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
@IBOutlet weak var selectedChoice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var field: UITextField!


var choices = [String]()

 //first button that adds string to array
@IBAction func addToChoices(_ sender: Any) {

    choices.append(field.text!)

    print(choices)
    print(choices.count)
}



   //button that I want to disable once 'choices.isEmpty' but enable it again after more strings are added to 'choices'
  @IBAction func shuffleTilExhuasted(_ sender: Any) {
    let button = sender as? UIButton


    let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(choices.count)))

    selectedChoice.text = choices[rand]
    choices.remove(at: rand)

    switch choices.isEmpty {
    case true:
        button?.isEnabled = false
    case false:
        button?.isEnabled = true
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re enable it when add , create IBOutlet of the button

```
//first button that adds string to array
@IBAction func addToChoices(_ sender: Any) {

    choices.append(field.text!)
    self.btn.isEnabled = true
    print(choices)
    print(choices.count)
}
```

OR use didSet with the array

```
var choices:[String] = []
{
    didSet {
       self.btn.isEnabled = choices.isEmpty
    }
}
```

Comment: Using didSet seems like the way to go. I was entering that as an answer when I saw that you already suggested it. (Voted.)